# How do i get Rails to route to a controller instead of a static file in the public folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

In a Rails 2.3 app I have a `SitemapController` with a `sitemap` action that creates a human-readable sitemap page, and a route to that in the routes file. In the public folder there's a `sitemap.xml` file for search engines. The problem is that `http://mysite/sitemap` is serving up `sitemap.xml`, and not routing to the controller. If I delete `sitemap.xml` then it routes to the controller just fine.

On several other very similar sites we have the exact same arrangement, but on those the existence of `sitemap.xml` does *not* prevent Rails from routing to the controller. On those sites, as expected, `http://mysite/sitemap` routes to `SitemapController#sitemap` and `http://mysite/sitemap.xml` serves the static file. Yet I've been unable to discover any difference that could be causing this problem.

Can anyone suggest what might be causing this, or how I might go about debugging it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a function of how you're hosting your application. Different web server environments have defaults that can affect this. For instance, Apache will tend to serve a static file at a higher priority than a call to your application, but it can be configured to not serve static files at all if you are using something like Passenger.

The way you alter this is highly dependent on the web server software you are using.

Comment: You are correct. The problem turned out to be differing Apache configuration files. It turns out we need to disable [MultiViews](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_multiviews_mod_negotiation) to be compatible with Passenger.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like :

```
class SiteMapController
  def sitemap
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xml { render :file => "/any/path/you/want/to/your/sitemap.xml" }
      # you can then add other formats, like html, for a more human-readable response
    end
  end
```

and delete the xml in /public.

more info : http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_to