# How to ensure controller is called when static file exists in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a link '/example' that works fine unless I place a static file example.html in /public folder, it loads static file then instead. How can I make sure that '/example' will call the controller and '/example.html' will load the static file.

I have as follows in _routes.rb file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'example', to: 'base#index', as: :example
```

Comment: I believe this post is providing the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363725/how-do-i-get-rails-to-route-to-a-controller-instead-of-a-static-file-in-the-publ

Comment: I believe it does not make sense

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i get Rails to route to a controller instead of a static file in the public folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363725/how-do-i-get-rails-to-route-to-a-controller-instead-of-a-static-file-in-the-publ)

Answer (score 0):

I looked into answers to post from comment. I'm not sure if this is server related as I had the same behaviour on both Puma and Passenger so ultimately went with the second option: renamed example.html to example2.html added following to base controller (key was layout: false)

```
 def example_html
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render layout: false, :file => Rails.root / 'public' / "example2.html" }
    end
  end
```

and added following to routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'example.html', to: 'base#example_html'
```